# Tight coupling in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, single-responsibility-principle

I have django model which contains `incident_type` and `closed` fields. Based on this fields I want to return functions that render some text.

Is it okay to have such `get_renderer` method in models or I should move this logic somewhere else? In my understanding, this method violates single responsibility principle.

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    BAD_RESPONSE = 'bad_response'
    SLOW_RESPONSE = 'slow_response'
    INCIDENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (BAD_RESPONSE, 'Webpage is not available'),
        (SLOW_RESPONSE, 'Webpage is slow'),
    )

    incident_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=INCIDENT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    closed = models.BooleanField()

    def get_renderer(self):
        if self.incident_type == self.BAD_RESPONSE:
            if self.closed:
                return render_page_up_screen
            else:
                return render_page_down_screen
```

Comment: When you say render some text, do you mean render that text to the UI? Send it to a web page?

Comment: These functions render json [attachments](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments) for Slack bot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think it would be more appropriate to locate this method somewhere in your view layer. Keeping your model loosely coupled from web and rendering related concepts is generally good practice. It keeps the model flexible and more adaptable to change.

Moving `get_renderer()` into your view should be straightforward? It would still have access to the `indicdent_type` and `closed` fields via an `Indcident` instance to make its rendering decision.

Comment: I agree with your opinion and probably will do it this way, but if I'll move `get_renderer` method outside, I'll be forced to inspect `Incident` object state outside, which is violating "Tell, don't ask" principle. These design principles are confusing. I think, I just have to prioritize SRP over Tell don't ask.